# c program to add all even numbers in array and subtract all odd numbers in array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that returns a number which is all even numbers added to the total from the array, subtracted by all the odd numbers in the array. But I am getting 0 but the output should be 2.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add_even_sub_odd(const int data[], int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] % 2 == 0) {
            total + data[i];
            printf("%d\n", data[i]);
        }

        else {

            total - data[i];
            printf("%d\n", data[i]);

        }
    }
    return total;
    
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printf("%d\n", add_even_sub_odd(data, 4));
}
```

Comment: `total = total + data[i]`, same for minus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a value to a C and C++ variable, you use an assignment expression. Assignment expressions assign a value to the left operand. The left operand must be a modifiable lvalue. An lvalue is an expression representing a data object that can be examined and altered.

***Simple assignment operator :***

```
total = total + data[i];
total = total - data[i];
```

OR

***Compound assignment operators :***

```
total += data[i];
total -= data[i];
```

**EDIT :** Alternatively you can also even use following code replacing if-else statement(not right or wrong, just looks fun)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_even_sub_odd(const int data[], int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        total+=abs(data[i]%2)*(-2)*data[i] + data[i];
    }
    return total;
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[6] = {-1, 2, 3, 4,-4,1};
    printf("%d\n", add_even_sub_odd(data, 6));
}
```